# how to execute stored procedure asynchronously using JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, asynchronous, stored-procedures

I want to call one Stored Procedure from java function asynchronously that means my function should not wait whether that Stored Procedure executed or not. It should simply call that Stored Procedure and it should not wait for execution. I have tried with thread, Is there any other way to execute stored procedure asynchronously?

```
public void callLogonDetailSP(UserDetails userInfoSharedObject) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            int i = logonUserDetailsRepository.callLogonDetailSP(userInfoSharedObject.userName, userInfoSharedObject.password, userInfoSharedObject.userCityName);

        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: That's pretty much all you need, but you might have some performance issue depending on how many threads you end up making. You should use a thread pool to limit the max number of threads that will be spawned by the application, but still allow you to schedule the work asynchronously.

Comment: I'd say add all these jobs to a queue, and limit the maximum number of threads like flakes said. Use the queue to store the jobs so when threads reach there max limit you can still execute them once any thread becomes free.

Comment: What if there's a problem with the call? You'll just ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

A more advanced alternative to `Thread` objects are Executor services. More info here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

These can be created with the static methods of the `Executors` class. Some of the like `newSingleThreadExecutor()` manages 1 thread, but if more is needed you can use `newFixedThreadPool(int n)` which will create an executor service managing `n`  threads.

These classes also use a `Future` object which represents the result of your task (the result is not yet calculated but you get a reference to it anyways, hence the name).

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable<Integer> c = new Callable<>() {
    @Override public Integer call() {
         return 0; //do some task here that returns an integer
    }
}; 
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(c);
```

Notice that both `Callable` and `Future` are generic so you can use any class as the result of your background task.

FOR ANDROID:
If you develop for android you can use the `AsyncTask` as well. Very useful, since normally the android UI elements can only be modified from the UI thread, but this class provides methods that run AFTER your task was completed and on the UI thread.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask